# Is it possible for a template argument to equal the value of another element?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
<h1 class="profile_username"></h1>

<a href="{% url 'profile' user= %}"></a>
```

`h1` will be dynamically populated with a value, so is it possible for the `user` argument to equal the value of the `h1` class?

Comment: Are you talking about post rendering of the template? what dynamically populates the class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but a GET ajax call populates it: `success: function (data) {
            $('.profile_username').html(data.username);`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to first provide a false user that will allow django to resolve the url template tag (and you may also want to provide an id to make your javascript easier to reference

```
<a id="my_user_link" href="{% url 'profile' user='frodo' %}"></a>
```

You can then do a string replace and change this user string to your dynamic one

```
var a_link = $('#my_user_link');
a_link.attr('href', a_link.attr('href').replace('frodo', data.username));
```

The same applies if your `user` kwarg is a number, just pick a random number that you can guarrantee won't affect any other part of the constructed url (i.e 666) and replace that with the required value